# Who can see my deleted answer?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I have recently posted an answer and deleted it since I have thought it as a different question, then I deleted my answer. I am still able to see my answer to the question. I am afraid that someone will think of it as a Good answer.

Is there any way to delete the answer completely with no one able to see it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Users with 10k reputation and ♦ moderators will still be able to see the answer as well. But they can't (down)vote it, nor will they post comments on it.

> Is there any way to delete the answer completely with no one able to see it?

No, because there's no need for this. The fact that it's deleted will tell people that it is not useful.

Comment: But don't have high-rep users and/or mods the power to un-delete the post (even if it's not theirs)?

Comment: Yes, they do. For high-rep users, it will take three of them to undelete a specific post. And mod-deleted posts cannot be undeleted by normal users.

Comment: Technically moderators can comment on deleted posts -- it's just very rarely required, but it's doable.

Comment: Can you downvote them as well (in theory)?

Comment: @Glorfindel nope.

Comment: If it is, as OP seems to be afraid of, actually a *good* answer, then I might copy it and grab the points! No duplicate answer, no plagiarism to be seen. (Unless you are >10K or the OP.)

Comment: @RadLexus if it is really a good answer, then why delete it?

Comment: You'll have to ask the OP.